# Should the plausibility and imaginability of a theory play a role in its prior probability?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

In Bayesianism, every theory has a certain prior probability. Now of course, this can be a very subjective task, and so I am anticipating that there is no correct answer, but am still curious for a response.

Now, certain theories may seem more implausible than others simply because they are necessarily more improbable. For example, it makes sense to give the prior probability of supernaturalism in general a higher or equal value than a specific god. The former contains the latter.

But what about theories that haven’t been tested and yet are differentiated by how plausible they seem. For example, a god who is bored and plays a random draw by people’s names and then decides which person to help that day may seem less plausible and harder to imagine than a god who decides to help someone who did good deeds that day.

Of course, there is no verifiable or testable evidence of either. But should one of these be given a higher or lower prior probability simply by the ease it which it is imagined?

Comment: I found it easier to imagine a giant pink rabbit living on Mars than a microscopic purple hyena living on an unnamed planet in a galaxy I have never heard of. Does that make the former more likely?

Comment: Your examples are hilarious sometimes  I suppose the answer depends on how one defines likely. But if I had to guess, no, they’re equally unlikely

Comment: The latter of course is far more likely.   A cold planet with no water and little atmosphere is unlikely to support rabbits of any color or size. But with near infinite galaxies of planets to develop on, a complex animal that both approximates a hyena and is tiny and purple is reasonably plausible.  So Marco’s imagination misled him.

Comment: Ha! Cheers, guys!

Comment: @Dcleve I think his point is that in the case of options we haven’t even confirmed to be possible, it makes no sense to discuss what is more or less likely among them.

Comment: But I can’t tell if you were being serious with that @Dcleve 

Comment: I'd intended the silly examples to be the lead-in to a longer answer but didn't have time to think it through. I was wondering about string theory. Would you consider it to be an easily imagined idea (ie that everything was just vibrating strings) or an enormously complicated and impenetrable mathematical challenge.

Comment: I love you Marco

Comment: @thinkingman -- Yes I am absolutely serious.  I was doing order of magnitude plausibility checks.  Both animals as an approximations (they would not fit into our animal kingdom, but could be considered animals anyway)  are likely existing in the universe somewhere.  Just not on Mars.

Comment: @MarcoOcram -- It is relatively easy for us to come up with ideas in broad terms.  However, when we don't understand a subject in detail, we dramatically underestimate how complicated the implementation has to be.  This is why program managers always think tasks are easy and being done too slowly, and cost/schedule estimating needs to be done by specialists in a field.  The general idea of string theory is simple.  The actual implementation is immensely complex.  Here is a good book on it.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3JVQDAK1408BR/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B000SEOB2Q

Comment: You don’t have enough information to talk about how likely that kind of animal is in the universe. @Dcleve

Comment: I think the title needs some work.  The prior probability *is* a measure of it's (a-priori) plausibility (at least in a subjectivist Bayesian framework).

Comment: @thinkingman -- current abiogenesis research suggests abiogenesis is radically unlikely naturally, but researchers can plausibly speculate they have missed a key assumption or two that could dramatically change that.  It is reasonable in naturalism to infer that actual existence is probable,  which requires either common abiogenesis, or common miraculous abiogenesis.  Life can therefore reasonably inferred to be commonplace.  Animals (capture resources actively) are the basic form of life, plants are more complex (they supplement capture with manufacture).

Comment: Therefore there will be MULTITUDES of systems with life in our universe, dominated by animal-like structures.  It is vanishingly implausible that hundreds of those structures will not look like a rabbit, so one will very likely be a pink rabbit.  Meanwhile gravity plays a key role in size -- in high Gs living structures will be small, in low G they will be large.  Life can be supported in high and low G environments, so there will be large and small "rabbits", etc.

Comment: I don’t have enough information or knowledge on how life may have started to determine how likely or possible it would be to arise elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer to this question is irreducibly subjective (as some founders of Bayesian statistics such as de Finetti or Ramsey may probably also have said). A probability subjectivist would accept arguments based on coherence, i.e., they would accept that a superset cannot have a smaller probability than a subset, so not *all* probability assignments are arbitrary, but when it comes to the situation you are asking about, I don't see any logical or objective reason to enforce anything other than your subjective choices.